# How reset auto increament field to start from 1?

Tags: mysql

I use wamp server in local host. I have an auto increment field with "ID" name in MySQL. After empty the table content the value of ID continue from old value. I'm trying to reset the the beginning value of this field to 1 after empty the table. How I can do this?

Comment: OK, thanks, but the link on that page doesn't work, so I didn't know how use TRUNCATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncate table automatically reset the Autoincrement values to 0.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should truncate your table.

```
TRUNCATE `[Your_table_name]`;
```